# Sharepoint 2013 FieldFormCollection issue

Tags: 2013

I have faced the problem with accessing form fields in Sharepoint foundation 2013.

Idea is to update some field automatically when new form opens. I created a custom web part and attached it to the new form. I tried to access : SPContext.Current.FormContext.FieldControlCollection form field control collection, but it does not contain any form fields. Instead there are some hidden fields that are not needed for me.

There was no problem with accessing form fields in SharePoint 2010, but in SharePoint 2013 it seems that it is a bug.

I hope that someone have already faced the same problem and will provide some solution or recommendations how to deal with this issue.

Besides,
The same problem is in both sharepoint 2013 versions (foundation and server)

Thanks,
Karolis

Answer (score 0):

In SP2013 and later, fields are rendered in client side (CSR). If you need to render fields server side and see them in FieldControlCollection, you need to set that on your form settings. Open NewForm.aspx in edit mode, change Form webpart properties  and set below parameter to ServerSide:

[image]